# Change speed of HTML Title tag showing up

Tags: html

Is there a way to change how quickly/slowly the contents of the title tag will show up when text is hovered over?

e.g.

```
<h1 title="show up title">
```

Answer (score 3):

this all require the JavaScript or jquery

try this

html

```
<h1   id="book" title="hello onw"  >the title </h1>
```

jquery

```
    $("#book").append("<em></em>");
 $("#book").hover(function() {
      $(this).find("em").animate({opacity: "show", top: "-75"}, "slow");
      var hoverText = $(this).attr("title");
      $(this).find("em").text(hoverText);
    }, function() {
      $(this).find("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-85"}, "fast");
    });
```

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/QSgdD/)

also check [this](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/animated-hover2.html) out